# Getting loss nan with GPU after half an epoch but never with CPU

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nan, nvidia

When training with GPU i see fairly large fluctuations in loss and val-loss and quite fast i get loss NaN.
If i reduce the learning rate by a lot I'm able to sometimes keep it from going loss NaN. But the model performance is quite bad.

This initialization values between my CPU and GPU training is the same as i save the model to disk and starts training from that file for both CPU and GPU.

I have tried clip value, norm value

If I use CPU for training i can use high learning rates and I see a steady decrease of loss and val-loss. Even at the same learning rate as with GPU the CPU sees lower loss and val-loss for same number of epochs.

I'm training a model with 3 LSTM branches(32 parameters input), each LSTM branch has a layer of 512 units and another with 128 units, concatenated and then 2 x dense layers of 265 units.
I use a small amount of l2 reg(0.00001) on the LSTM layers and small dropout(0.05) on the dense layers. I have tried with and without dropout and L2 reg.

I'm using standard mean squared loss.

The model architecture does not seams to have anything to do with my problem as i have tried a lot of different layers and parameters.
Batch size does not seams to have an effect. I tried very low batch sizes.
I have tried:
Various regulation techniques.
Clip value
Norm value
Lower learning rate
GPU burn test (no errors)
Lots of different model architectures. Even some without LSTM layers.

My GPU is a GTX 1080. I have tried a burn test. Shows 0 errors.

I use
Tensorflow 2.13
cuDNN 8.6
Nvidia driver 535.86.05

This is my model:

```
num_properties = 12
dropout_rate = 0.05
l2_reg_value = 0.00001

input_branch1 = Input(shape=(32, num_properties))
input_branch2 = Input(shape=(32, num_properties))
input_branch3 = Input(shape=(32, num_properties))

lstm_branch1 = LSTM(512, return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg_value))(input_branch1)
lstm_branch1 = LSTM(128, kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg_value))(lstm_branch1)

lstm_branch2 = LSTM(512, return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg_value))(input_branch2)
lstm_branch2 = LSTM(128, kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg_value))(lstm_branch2)

lstm_branch3 = LSTM(512, return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg_value))(input_branch3)
lstm_branch3 = LSTM(128, kernel_regularizer=l2(l2_reg_value))(lstm_branch3)

concatenated = concatenate([lstm_branch1, lstm_branch2, lstm_branch3])

dense = Dense(256, activation='selu')(concatenated)
dense = Dropout(dropout_rate)(dense)
dense = Dense(256, activation='selu')(dense)
dense = Dropout(dropout_rate)(dense)

output = Dense(1, activation='linear')(dense)

model = Model(inputs=[input_branch1, input_branch2, input_branch3], outputs=output)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, clipnorm=1), loss="mae")
```

Any suggestions?

I just tried to train with the exact same model and training data on a Lambda GPU cloud machine with A10 GPU. No problems.

So the problem is with my PC or versions of tensorflow ect.
I tried to reinstall Ubuntu and followed the installationinstructions from tensorflow. Same problem.

Next thing i will try is another GPU.

Comment: Please add the code you're using.

Comment: Does the problem persist if you use a known-good dataset? E.g. MNINST with just two dense layers?

Comment: @MSalters I will give that a try and let you know how that turns out.

Comment: @MSalters I tried the example from https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/keras_example

Its seams fine. No difference between GPU and CPU

Epoch 6/6
469/469 [==============================] - 1s 1ms/step - loss: 0.0586 - sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9828 - val_loss: 0.0766 - val_sparse_categorical_accuracy: 0.9770

Comment: @mhenning I Added the model that I'm currently using. But as mentioned i have tried many different models with the same result. And my current model and training data works fine when using CPU or on Lambda GPU instance.

Answer (score 0):

The GTX 1080 was the problem even trough it doesn't seams faulty in any other way.

Replacing it with a RTX 3090 solves the problem.